# How to add delay in Omnet++?

Tags: time, delay, omnet++, exponential, uniform

Actually, The idea is that when a person get infected it becomes sick after some time (days or even weeks). How to do so? How could I add some time(or delay) into my code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Schedule a self-message into the future. At that specific time point, the message will be delivered to the `handleMessage()` method where you can act accordingly.

Comment: Well, I know I have to schedule a self message but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You definitely have to read the documentation and do the 'tictoc' tutorial to get the basics.